# Component isn't reading new state change after button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Basically I have a button that changes the value of the state when I click it, in my parent component the state is read and check for that value and displays some HTML depending on that value. However it seems that the state in the parents isn't actually changing.

The child is modifying `displayOptions` in the `handleClick()` function
Parent component:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    dataType: "", // store the type of data for the type of operation that should be sent to the backend. For example "create" will have the data for creating data
    data: {},
    displayOptions: false,
    leads: []
    } 

    // have CRUD options that are displayed when user clicks on a lead. When on of the options are selected
    // display the appropriate fields
  }
  leads = []
  async handleChange(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    // use console.log here otherwise it won't show the desired value for state on the first click
    // this.setState({displayOptions: true}, () => console.log(this.state)) 
    // now get the details for each lead from backend

  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    var leads = await getAllLeads((data) => {return data});
    leads = JSON.parse(leads)
    this.setState({ leads });
    console.log("REF", this.state.displayOptions)
  }

  // <HomePage dataState={this.state}/>
  // then if the dataType isn't empty display the HTML for those fields
  // 
  render() {
    // when one of the leads is clicked, display options
    if(this.state.dataType === "" && this.state.displayOptions === true){
        console.log("DISPLAY OPTIONS")
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1> Select a lead</h1>
            <Card Obj={this.state} />
          </div>
        )

    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1> Select lead {this.state.displayOptions} </h1>
          <Card Obj={this.state} />
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

child component that alters it's `props`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showMenu: false,
    };

    this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
    this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
  }

  showMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }

  closeMenu(event) {

    if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

      this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
      }); 

    }
  }

  handleClick(arg){
      console.log("HEREw", arg)
      this.props.Obj.displayOptions = arg
      console.log(this.props.Obj)
  }

  render() {
    //console.log("SUPPLIER", this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.Obj.leads.map(lead => <a href={lead.first_name} onClick={this.showMenu}> 
            {lead.first_name} {lead.last_name} <br /><br /></a>)} 
        {
          this.state.showMenu
            ? (
              <div
                className="menu"
                ref={(element) => {
                  this.dropdownMenu = element;
                }}
              >
                <button value="update" onClick={() => this.handleClick(true)}> Update </button>
                <button value="create" onClick={() => this.handleClick(true)}> Create </button>
              </div>
            )
            : (
              null
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card
```

After I `console.log` the value of `displayOptions` is the correct value in the child component, but not the parent, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quite update a prop by setting it to a new value. Even though it seems like the prop updated in `Card`, it is only a copy of the actual `props` and it won't ever be rendered in your component if you need it.

If you want to modify `displayOptions` inside `Card`, you want to pass in a callback function as a prop to `Card`.

For example:

```
// in App.js 
updateDisplayOptions = (newOptions) => {
  this.setState({displayOptions: newOptions})
}}

// in App.js render()
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1> Select lead {this.state.displayOptions} </h1>
    <Card Obj={this.state} updateOptions={updateDisplayOptions}/>
  </div>
)

// in Card.js
handleClick(arg){
  this.props.updateOptions(arg)
  // right after, Obj won't be updated, but it will asynchronously update, then 
  // rerender your React components, with the newly updated display options
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm getting the error: `TypeError: this.props.updateOptions is not a function` Did it work for you?

Comment: nvm I made a mistake but I have a new error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState is not a function`

Comment: Yes it is, I alwaso have a `constructor` which I put `this.updateDisplayOptions = this.updateDisplayOptions.bind(this)` inside and it seems to be working now. Does that make sense?

Comment: However it seems that if I click it twice it gives the error again

Comment: I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-water-zcuxb) which I think works as expected with the changes outlined in the answer (no need to bind if you're using an arrow function). Only other change is replacing `getLeads` with static data. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That is working thank you, I have a different question as well. I can open a new question if needs be, but I want the buttons for create and update to appear under each link. Rather than appear at the very bottom like it is now. I tried using the `map()` function I have there but it doesn't work. How would I go about using map() to show that menu for each link?

Comment: Pass down some extra prop to `<Card />` that says which index you're editing (-1 if not editing any). When you're rendering the leads, if the current element is the one that matches the one you're rendering, instead of rendering `<a>`, you'd wanter render a `div` that contains the `a` tag plus your buttons. `updateDisplayOptions`, would then also need to include the index of lead you want to be editing`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow yet, how would that insure that the buttons only appear below the selected lead? When I'm defining that extra index wouldn't `Card` need to do that? Not `App`? Since `Card` is where I'm selecting the lead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210349/discussion-between-kevin-bai-and-charles-smith).